# How to find the serial port number on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, serial-port, arduino

I have just started experimenting with Serproxy and Arduino to get some serial data into Flash Builder/Flex. Serproxy seems to work fine and seems to connect to whatever port is specified. However, I am not able to see or read any data from the serial port using ActionScript. This is odd, because the Arduino should be printing data on a loop.

The only thing I can think of is that I am not setting the correct serial port number. I have been trying to figure out how to find out what number should be set, that is, 5331, 5332, 5333, etc.

How do I find out the port number? Is there a way to do this using Terminal on OS X maybe?

Comment: Not sure about OSX but on other systems you can monitor the serial port by going to Tools->Serial Port Monitor in the Arduino IDE

Comment: Consider changing the title of this question to something that reflects the selected answer.  Maybe "How to read a serial port on Mac OSX Terminal?"

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can find your Arduino via Terminal with

```
 ls /dev/tty.*
```

then you can read that serial port using the screen command, like this

```
screen /dev/tty.[yourSerialPortName] [yourBaudRate]
```

for example:

```
screen /dev/tty.usbserial-A6004byf 9600
```

Answer (score 27):

Try this:
`ioreg -p IOUSB -l -b | grep -E "@|PortNum|USB Serial Number"`

Comment: This is very nice, but how is this translated into the name in `/dev/`?

Comment: Any solution about this translation?

Comment: It seems doable manually, each port has a port number, and its parent, grandparent ... , each has a port number too. If you join the number together, you get a subset of your serial port. Not sure what is the best way to do it programmatically to parse the tree.

Comment: At least in later macOS versions, the "USB Serial Number" is simply concatenated to `/dev/tty.usbmodem` or `/dev/cu.usbmodem`

Answer (score 3):

I was able to screen using the device's name anyway so that wasn't the issue. I was actually just trying to find the port number, i.e. 5331, 5332 etc. I managed to find this by a trial and error process using an app called TCP2Serial from the app store on Mac OS X. It isn't free but that's fine as long as I know it works!

Worth the 99c :)
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tcp2serial/id506186902?mt=12

Comment: There are not so many port numbers? In my case you can easily see which is the port number for the arduino: `imac: username$ ls /dev/tty.*
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem /dev/tty.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync /dev/tty.usbserial-A4001sy9
`

Comment: But what is the serial com port number? com1, com2, com8, etc?

Answer (score 3):

mac os x don't use com numbers. you have to use something like
'ser:devicename' , 9600

Answer (score 0):

While entering the serial port name into the code in arduino IDE, enter the whole port address i.e:

```
/dev/cu.usbmodem*
```

or

```
/dev/cu.UG-*
```

where the `*` is the port number.

And for the port number in case of mac just open terminal and type

```
ls /dev/*
```

and then search for the port that u have set in arduino IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share a much fun way for watching your serial port on Mac.

Step1: Run this command in your terminal with your device connected and then run with your device not connected `ls /dev/tty.*` . Which ever port appear/disappears, that one is the port you are wanting to work with For e.g `/dev/tty.URT2` in my case.

Step2: Go to Mac App Store and install `Termius`. It is a really cool and aesthetic application for watching your ports and performing other types of experimentation.

Step3: Start `Termius`, Click on `Hosts` tab, then click on `Serial` button, then pick your Serial Port from the dropdown and select Baudrate.

Step4: Press `Connect`. Wollah, you are watching your port now.

Answer (score -1):

Found the port esp32 was connected to by -

```
ls /dev/*
```

You would get a long list and you can find the port you need